# issue with UIButton image in UITableCellView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I am making a simple timer app. I have a uitable with multiple rows. In that table I have put a UIButton. Everything works and so far so good i.e. I see the button appear in each row. What I needed to do next was to set an image for the UIButton e.g. if the timer was running I wanted to show stop_button_image in the UIButton and if the timer had started I wanted to set the UIImage on the button to start_button_image

The problem is that if the table gets refreshed then I get a nasty traceback depending upon where I had put the UIButton setimage code. Here is my code for reference.

```
//WORKING CODE: (NOT THAT I WANT)
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //TESTING - Button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            // Use the default cell style.
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            //TESTING - Button
            [button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(timerStopStart:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [button setTitle:@"Start/Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 72.0f, 77.0f);
            button.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell addSubview:button];

    //THIS WORKS IF I PUT THIS HERE
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else 
        {
             //NSLog(@"went here 2");
             button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
        }

//some other logic
    }
```

//CODE BREAKS HERE

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            //TESTING - Button
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                // Use the default cell style.
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                //TESTING - Button
                [button addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(timerStopStart:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
                [button setTitle:@"Start/Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 72.0f, 77.0f);
                button.tag = indexPath.row;
                [cell addSubview:button];


            }
            else 
            {
                 //NSLog(@"went here 2");
                 button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
            }

//CODE BREAKS HERE
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //some other logic
        }
```

The problem is that when the table gets refreshed it calls the section with code button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]; which I know is just a reference.

Here is the error I get in iOS simulator. I really want to put that image code outside the cell==null check. Any clues how this can be done?

Here is the error that I get in the simulator

```
2012-06-14 12:39:27.246 Timers[5381:10a03] -[UITableViewCell setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73706e0
2012-06-14 12:39:27.247 Timers[5381:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73706e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x150b052 0x16bbd0a 0x150cced 0x1471f00 0x1471ce2 0x136c6 0x7b5e0f 0x7b6589 0x7a1dfd 0x7b0851 0x75b322
```

Comment: Try button.tag = indexPath.row + someoffset; The 0 row might be your issue.

Comment: @thelaws - thank you. You are right row 0 was killing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably when the indexPath.row is zero. In that case, you call `viewWithTag:0` but as the tag of any UIView is 0 by default, there are chances that a lot of your cell's subview have a tag with the value 0, not only your UIButton.

To avoid this issue, try adding a constant (like 100) to your indexPath.row before affecting it to the tag, so that your button at row 0 will have the tag 100 and not 0 (and button at row 1 will have the tag 101, and so on…), avoiding it to be confused with any other subview with tag 0.

Comment: thank you so much. That did the trick. I added 100 in the code as per your suggestions and its happy now. phew! button.tag = (indexPath.row)+100; button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:((indexPath.row)+100)];

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this will fail for row 0.

```
button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

will return cell when indexPath.row is 0, because cell.tag is 0.

---

As a general note, this approach will not work. The first time you reuse a cell the button will have the wrong tag. For example, if you reuse the cell from row 2 in row 18, then the tag on the button will be 2, but the tag you look for is 18. It will return `nil`.

why not define a constant `#define kMyStopStartButtonTag 12345` and use that constant the whole time.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    …
    button.tag = kMyStopStartButtonTag;
    [cell addSubview:button];
    …
} else {
    button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:kMyStopStartButtonTag];
}
```

Comment: The reason I can't define a constant is that I have button next to each row in the cell and I need to know which one the user pressed i.e. which timer is the user trying to start/stop

Comment: @SamBudda `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)button.superview]` in `-(IBAction)timerStopStart:(UIButton *)button;` will get you the indexPath of the cell from the button.