# Detecting which button is clicked in UITableview and changing button image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using three tables in my view and seprating them each other using a tag. In my second table view i made a cutom uitableview and adding labels and buttons inside them .

this is the button which i wrote inside the cellforrowatindexpath

```
followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

  [followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

following.tag=indexpath.row;

 [followingButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);

 [cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];
```

======

```
-(void)followingButtonpressed:(id)sender
{

 UIView *contentView1 = (UIView *)[sender superview];

 UITableViewCell *cell1= (UITableViewCell *)[contentView1 superview];

 NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [followingTable indexPathForCell:cell1];

[sender tag];

NSLog(@"sender tag --%d",[sender tag]);

 // UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

 // UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[button superview];

  UIButton *tempButtom = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:[sender tag]];

  [tempButtom setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_off12.png"] 

forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

But its crashing and i was not able to change the image of selected button , please help

Comment: At what point your app is crashing, try to add an Exception breakpoint, its second last tab to the right of your project navigator.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this to detect which button has been pressed

    UIView *senderButton = (UIView*) sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: (UITableViewCell*)[[senderButton superview]superview]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037617/issue-with-uibutton-image-in-uitablecellview

Answer (score 0):

Give `Tag` to each `UIButton` and write following code for detect which button is pressed

```
 - (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   // Get the UITableViewCell which is the superview of the UITableViewCellContentView which is the superview of the UIButton
   (UITableViewCell*)cell = [[button superview] superview];
   int row = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell].row;

  // Here **row** give you tad of specific UIButton that you tapped

  if (row == yourTag )
  {
     // write code for action
  }
}
```

**Or you can set tag for cell each time, but not UIButton. Your action will look then:**

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{ 
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   int row = [button superview].tag;

   // Here **row** give you tad of specific UIButton that you tapped

  if (row == yourTag )
  {
     // write code for action
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem is probably when the indexPath.row is zero. In that case, you call viewWithTag:0 but as the tag of any UIView is 0 by default, there are chances that a lot of your cell's subview have a tag with the value 0, not only your UIButton.

To avoid this issue, try adding a constant (like 100) to your indexPath.row before affecting it to the tag, so that your button at row 0 will have the tag 100 and not 0 (and button at row 1 will have the tag 101, and so on…), avoiding it to be confused with any other subview with tag 0.

This helped me

Comment: in short in my code you get `UIButton` Tag that you pressed ....and write your code related button tag :)